# Possible to have different branches with completely different files / file structures?

Tags: git

I'm working on a project where I have a file structure based on a CMS. I'd also like to have a structure of files for a dev server to test things out.

What would be the best way / practice to handle branches where one branch ("cms") would hold one set of files and the other ("dev-server") could hold a completely different set of files? Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You probably don't want to do this.  Are these files system critical, and how/why do they differ from what's in production?

Comment: This is definitely possible, but it rather defeats a lot of the purpose for using `git` to begin with. Perhaps you should just have a separate repo for each...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yeah - sounds like a new repo might be the best route. The repo would need to be private, so was just thinking about possible ways to group everything into one repo and not adding a separate repo to go over my limit of private repos. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is technically possible with git - you don't want to do it.
Different set of files means different git repositories.